# R.java missing caused by menu

Tags: android, r.java-file

If I delete the file in the menu folder R.java generated but the app wont work when ran.

However if I put it back it wont generate R.java.

What can I do?

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: _"If I delete the file in the menu folder R.java generated but the app wont work when ran"_ I don't understand what you are asking here. AFAIK, R.java is automatically generated by Android within your project so you don't need to do anything with it. Are you having problems generating the R.java file?

Comment: yes and it's cause by the file in the menu folder

Comment: Post a screenshot here illustrating the error so we can help you.

Comment: Post your menu.xml, we'll tell you if there's something wrong with it

Comment: I deleted it and put another one from a new project but even a new one didnt work

Comment: Maybe there are compilation errors with the xml file stored in the menu folder. You need to post the content of this file so we can see what you've done. FYI: The `menu` folder is required for an Android project structure.

Comment: I added it's content, it all seems alright

Comment: Is `action_settings` defined in `strings.xml?

Comment: yes it is, but now I notice that item has the same id, is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

The xml looks fine. It is probably due to @string/action_settings not existing anymore in your strings.xml (check exact spelling). Although the layout files will flag an error when this happens, for some reason the menu files don't; just no R file!